# Javascript Return False works in html, not head

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

`Return False` only seems to work inline, not in the document `<Head>`.

This works:

```
<html><body><form action="index.html" method="post">
<input type="submit" onClick="alert('Hello'); return false;">
</form>
</body></html>
```

This does not work:

```
<html><head>
function myfunction(){
alert("Hello");
return false;
}
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.html" method="post">
<input type="submit" onClick="myfunction();">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Comment: You've not posted what works?

Comment: Why is this surprising? In the first case you are returning something from the event handler and in the second case you don't. You return from `myfunction`, but not from the event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the "this works" part of your question, but I assume you meant to say onclick='alert("Hello"); return false;'. If so, for the second case to work, you have to pass on the value of the function to the parent element's onclick event. So basically, onclick='return myFunction()';